# javascript constructor function not giving correct result

Tags: javascript

i am a newbie to js.
i am trying to use constructor function to create an object.
here is my code

```
    function player(name,age,rank)
{

    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    this.rank=rank;
    this.sayEverything=function()
    {

        return "The name of the player is " + this.name + "the age is " + this.age + "the rank is " + this.rank; 
    }
```

Now i am adding a new property like this

```
player.matchReady=true;
```

now i create an object like this

```
var kaka=new player("kaka",22,3,false);
```

And when i write this

```
document.write('kaka is match ready-->' + kaka.matchReady);
```

it gives me this output
**kaka is match ready-->undefined**

Why is it giving me undefined?? 
haven't i added a new property correctly??Please tell me.
Thanks.

Comment: you should add this to kaka not to player!

Comment: ps: i wanna add a proerty later...

Comment: @Anil what if i wanna later add a property to player.

Comment: use prototype of js, like @Michael Dibbets has given an answer, already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `player.matchReady=true;`

Do, `player.prototype.matchReady = true;`

This way all players will have match ready default on true;

also you might want to put your function into the prototype.

```
player.prototype.sayEverything=function()
    {

        return "The name of the player is " + this.name + "the age is " + this.age + "the rank is " + this.rank; 
    }
```

You can regard prototype as the scaffolding on which you outline all properties and functions an object should have when it's instantiated. All these default values will be the same for all objects.

When you add functions within functions all these functions get duplicated in memory when you instantiate a new object.

When possible and when there is no need for scoping, try to add generic functions like your `sayEverything()`(please rename that to `toString()` to keep in line with convention) to the prototype.

That way all the player objects can use the same function. Which is more memory efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a property to a class. You can always add the property as its prototype.

like this:

```
function player(name, age, rank) {

     this.name = name;
     this.age = age;
     this.rank = rank;
     this.sayEverything = function () {

         return "The name of the player is " + this.name + "the age is " + this.age + "the rank is " + this.rank;
     }
 }

 player.prototype.matchReady = true;
 var kaka = new player("kaka", 22, 3, false);

 alert('kaka is match ready-->' + kaka.matchReady);
```

working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txchk9x3/)

[Blog on prototype](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-prototype-in-plain-detailed-language/)

Answer (score 1):

If you add it to the prototype, all player will have the field.

```
player.prototype.matchReady = true;
```

If you only want a specific player to have the field, add it to that player variable:

```
var kaka = new player("kaka",22,3,false); 
kaka.matchReady = true;// kaka has to come first
```

Answer (score 1):

In the below example you can see what is private ,public,static and privileged variable or method .When ever you write property on Method itself like static variable,that variable wont be available for the instances.

Also whenever you are writing constructor function you should follow the Naming convention to help you differentiate from other function

```
/ Constructor
function Player(name) {
    // Private
    var dob= "17/04/1986";

    // Privileged
    this.getDOB = function () {
        return dob;
    };

    // Public
    this.name = name;
}

// Public
Player.prototype.getName = function () {
    return this.name;
};

// Static property
Player.town = "South Park";
```